# How to get nested payload to Laravel layout view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-8

I have this payload and want to get assign individual param to layout view:

```php
  {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "some name",
            "option": {
                "name": "A",
                "description": "test test"
            },
            "desc": "test description",
            "media": [
                {
                    "name": "A",
                    "description": "Test test"
                }
            ],
            "default": {
                "level": {
                    "L": 10,
                    "B": 2,
                    "C": 10
                },
                "other": [
                    {
                        "name": "A",
                        "description": "Test test"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B",
                        "description": "Test test"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "C",
                        "description": "Test test"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
       
         @foreach($tests as $data)
                   
             @endforeach
```

Comment: Provide the code you tried, please.

Comment: @foreach($test as $data)
                        
                        <div class="box" data-animate="fadeInUp">
                            <div class="store card border-0 rounded-0">
                              {{ $data['name'] }}  // does not work
                           </div> 
                        </div>
     @endforeach
     
     Please  {{ $data['name'] }} return null;